# didSelectItemAtIndexPath doesn't work normally

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a problem when tap an item into CollectionView.

didSelectItemAtIndexPath doesn't called when tapped the item. Only execute this method when hold the item.

This is the method implementation.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath {

  NSLog(@"did select at index path %@", indexPath);
  _magazine = [[AppController instance] magazines][indexPath.row];
  [self loadEditionsForMagazine:_magazine];
  _magazineEditionsView.hidden = NO;
}
```

My CollectionView is linked to the datasource and delegate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these:

1. Nothing is upon your `UICollectionView`.
2. No subviews of `UICollectionView` receiving gesture before `UICollectionView`.
3. Or there is no other gesture recognition active.

Hope this helps.. :)